# Map data container volume to volume

Tags: mongodb, docker, volumes

I am using the (not official, as mentioned by Usman) mongodb image (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/dockerfile/mongodb/) which creates a volume at "/data/db"

**create mongdb container:**

```
docker build -t="dockerfile/mongodb" github.com/dockerfile/mongodb
```

**Run data container:**

```
docker run -v /data/db --name databox ubuntu:latest true
```

**run mongdb container with the data container (write mongo data into data container)**

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --volumes-from databox --name mongodb_shared_persistence dockerfile/mongodb
```

I tested it with:

```
docker run --volumes-from=databox busybox ls /data/db
```

...db files are created. So far so good.

But what if the data container has a volume at ***/mongodb/data*** and I want to map that to the ***/data/db*** volume of the mongodb container?

...like this:

```
docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v <?data_container_volume?>:/data/db --name mongodb dockerfile/mongodb
```

is that even possible?

Comment: Side note that is not an official image, Official images have a ribbon and the word Official Repo in the docker hub page e.g. https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mysql/. AFAIK there is no official mongo container but I find the dockerfile's use of docker logo and "trusted automated" in the description disingenuous.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail The official mongo image is at https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/mongo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the comments by shykes on [Issue 111](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/111):

> Volumes don't have top-level names. At no point does the user provide
>   a name, or is a name given to him. **Volumes are identified by the path
>   at which they are mounted inside their container.**

So I don't think there is any way to achieve this.

Comment: so in my case if I want to use a data container for more than one databse I would have to create multiple volumes e.g. /data/db (the mongodb one) , /data/mysql (guessing for mysql). that would be possible right? so if i don t want mongodb to use /data/db as volume I have to change the Dockerfile of the official mongodb Dockerfile

Comment: Yes you can have multiple volumes in side a container and volumes from will mount all of the volumes. If you wanted to link two different downstream mongo containers then you might have some trouble. In that case the down stream containers would need to have a configurable DB path.